# Freak error when attempting to run Forge server remotely via SSH

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I believe the problem could be with using Java 11. I'll downgrade to 8 and give it another shot.

I'm attempting to remotely start a Forge server via SSH but I'm continually receiving [this](https://pastebin.com/bnRMWL5Q) error. This issue does not occur when attempting to run it locally. Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
[java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1050]: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Comment: It's the parts of the stack trace that happen right before the `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` that will really tell you what the issue is

Comment: @RobOhRob Is that visible in the Pastebin?

Comment: Line 248 in file `ClassVisitor.java` is throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to Java 8 worked perfectly.